# Find all sequences whose range is contained in $\{0, 1, 2, ..., 9\}$ whose decimal expansion series have the same value.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define the series to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n 10^{-n-1}$ and find all sequences $x\neq y$ but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n 10^{-n-1} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n 10^{-n-1}$.

I don't see how this is ever true, I know for example that if x=99999....999 then the value of the series is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's true whenever you have one series ends in an infinite repetition of 9's and the other series ends 1 higher in the previous digit and then has an infinite number of 0s.  For example:
$.0200000000000.....=.0199999999999....$,  by the fact that these sums are defined by convergence, and both converge to $.02$

Edit:  This is also the only case this is true, because we need the two sequences to converge to the same number but not be identical, and the only way for that to happen is for at every single partial sum we get smaller and smaller differences, which only happens in this case.  The formal proof of that follows from that logic.